SQLite が起動出来ない
SQLiteのdll-win-x86をダウンロードしてコマンドプロンプトを開きファイル名をコピペして sqlite3 sample.db と入力しエンターを押したのですが起動できません。

スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　折角ご質問いただいたところ申し訳ないのですが、こちらの質問には何が問題になっているかを知るための情報が足りていません。質問者さんが使っている OS などの環境の情報と、起動できないというのはどういう状況なのか（〇〇というエラーが出ているとか、何もおきないまま復帰しないとか）を、質問文を [edit] して追記してみてください。参考: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

ファイル名から察するに恐らく Windows で、PATH が通っていないのが問題かと思われます。既に指摘のある通り、詳しい情報を追記するか、以下のサイトの手順等を参考に実施してみてください。 https://www.kkaneko.jp/tools/win/sqlite3.html


sqlite3 sample.db と入力しエンターを押したのですが起動できません。

「SQLiteのdll-win-x86をダウンロード」だけなら動かないでしょう。

SQLite から SQLite Download Page 開くと, 各種の環境ごとにいくつか用意されています

sqlite-tools-OS名*.zip

A bundle of command-line tools for managing SQLite database files, including the command-line shell program, the sqldiff program, and the sqlite3_analyzer program. (64-bit)

(適当な訳) SQLite データベース ファイルを管理するためのコマンドラインツール, コマンドラインシェル(たぶん sqlite3 コマンド)と sqldiffと sqlite3_analyzer が含まれて(バンドルされて)いる

sqlite-dll-win-*.zip
(たぶん 他の言語用, 例えば Pythonなどから利用するためのもの)

sqlite-wasm-*.zip
マルチプラットフォームだが, 環境構築が必要


sqlite3コマンド利用するなら sqlite-tools-OS名*.zipが必要で,
またダウンロードしたなら SHA3-256で誤りがないか確認したほうがよいでしょう。
あとは展開して使用するだけ
